# проверка Auth::user() в middleware

Tags: laravel5

Пытаюсь в `middleware` проверить, авторизован ли пользователь, пишу `Auth::user()`, а он возвращает `null`, причем в инете есть похожие примеры.

И тоже самое внутри моих контроллеров работает, а вот в `middleware` не работает, ощущение, что когда я вызываю middleware авторизация еще не выполнилась.

Но я вызываю его последним в разделе `protected $middleware`. Что я не так делаю?

Comment: Такая же проблема! Нашёл решение ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50597657/check-authuser-from-middleware?noredirect=1#comment88212668_50597657